# Magento 2 sitemap url does not work after we add any rewrite rule in root htaccess file

Tags: magento2.2, url-rewrite, sitemaps

Our sitemap URL works fine at /sitemap/sitemap.xml but as soon as we add any rewrite rule in root .htaccess file then it gives status code 404 page not found.

`RewriteRule ^abc/(.*)?$ /media/doc/files/abc/$1 [R=301,NC,L]`

Magento version **2.2.5**